# Need to restrict Bootstrap date picker to allow 1st day of each month only

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

With some business requirement I need to use date picker but the allowed dates are 1st of each month in past 10 years to future 2 years only.

I know I can do date range in date picker, but how can I have 1st day of each month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you can limit you range between 10 year ago and 2 years in the future using [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) and [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate) options. You can use [`beforeShowDay`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday) option to enable only the first day of each month between [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) and [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate), you simply have to check, for each displayed date, if the [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) is equal to 1.

Here a working sample:

```js
function addYears(num){
  var currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var currMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  return new Date(currYear+num, currMonth, 1);
}

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(d){
    if( d.getDate() === 1 ){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  startDate: addYears(-10),
  endDate: addYears(2)
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
```

If you want to use [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), you can use [`enabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enableddates) that accepts an array of enabled date. You can loop from 10 years ago till two year in the future creating the array of enabled dates. The componet uses momentjs, so you can use [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/), [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/), [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) to calculate your result. Note that moment object are mutable, so you have to use [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

Here a working sample:

```js
function getEnabledDays(){
  var arr = [];
  // Ten years ago
  var start = moment().startOf('month').subtract(10, 'years');
  // In two years
  var end = moment().startOf('month').add(2, 'years');
  while( start.isBefore(end) ){
    arr.push(start.clone());
    start.add(1, 'month');
  }
  return arr;
}

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'L',
  enabledDates: getEnabledDays()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it is great!

Comment: What we should do if we dont want past date like its showing 1st jan how can we disable it because its gone.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Perhaps your best bet will be to use the HTML5 `month` input type (`<input type="month">`) which allows you to select a month and a year. Apply the standard Bootstrap `form-control` class to the input. Note that it is not supported in Firefox or IE11.

### Method 2

Simply use drop-downs for the months and a numeral input with set limits with a text `<div>` containing the day for a readable interface.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the reason we prefer a date picker is that there are many other date pickers on the same screen. Business people wants to keep the consistency.

Comment: You can try to hook up an event handler so that when the date is changed in the picker The day will automatically be set to the 1st. I don't think that Bootstrap's default picker supports date-limitations. Perhaps a third party Bootstrap plugin does.